# How do I use match() for a white list of characters?

Tags: javascript

I used preg_match for my server-side validation but I want to have a client side too.

For my PHP I allow  those characters:

```
'/^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9 .:-,!?]+$/'
```

How would I make a white list of characters with `match()` in JavaScript?

EDIT:

I tried this but it didn't work for some reason:

My debugger says, right before the if statement:

`218SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: range out of order in character class`

```
$('#title').blur(function(){
      input = $('#title').val();
      var invalidChars = /^[^a-z][^a-z\d .:-,!?]+$/i;
    if (!invalidChars.test(input)){
         alert('true');     
         }
      else {
           alert('false');
           }
});
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this a validation for? (What data do you have that must start with a letter, but then can be followed with data so varied that it allows a space or exclamation point, but not an underscore?)

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. It is the title of an ad, user has to post. I am trying the codes right now. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var validChars = /^[a-z][a-z\d .:\-,!?]+$/i;
if (validChars.test(myText)){ ... }
```

Using `regex.test(str)` is slightly more performant than `str.match(regex)` if all you want is to know if a match exists or not.

Alternatively, you can early out if you see any invalid character:

```
var invalidChars = /^[^a-z][^a-z\d .:\-,!?]+$/i;
if (!invalidChars.test(myStr)){
  // we passed
}
```

This allows the regex test to stop the moment it sees a disallowed character.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I posted an edit of my code. Please let me know if you know what is wrong. THanks a lot

Comment: Woops; assuming you meant a literal hyphen in your second character set, you need to escape it (or have it as the last element in the set). I've edited my code appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

all of the above answers are correct, though just a side-note: instead of writing `[A-Za-z]`, a simple `/[a-z]/i` will suffice. The `i` is a case-insensitive flag...

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var text = ...;
if (text.match(/^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9 .:-,!?]+$/)) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The hyphen was causing problem in this code, but after escaping it now works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's the opposite:

```
var regexp = /^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z0-9 .:-,!?]+$/;

if (regexp.test(text)) {


}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The hyphen was causing problem in this code, but after escaping it now works. Thanks a lot

Comment: Instead of escaping the hyphen, place it at the very end of the [] class, like so: [a-zA-Z0-9 .:,!?-]

That way it won't be treated as the range operator.